# 16.04 can't connect to new skymuster NBN australia

Tags: networking, 16.04, ethernet

2 laptops asus k52dr 16.04/win 10 and Toshiba satellite L850 15.10/win10

In Australia a new satellite serving rural areas Skymuster replaced my previous satellite connection 26th Sep.

Both Win 10 and 15.10 connect.

The problem is that the laptop 16.04 will not connect to the NTD modem, whereas it did with the previous modem.

The ISP is of no help - only Windows.

Netcomm wireless router NF3ADV does not connect either

puzzling!

[ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk6B3.png)

[network manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guGvD.png)